# What's the minimum duty cycle which can be applied to a brushed DC motor?

Tags: motor, pwm, dc-motor, brushed-dc-motor

I am trying to control the speed of a brushed DC motor by varying its duty cycle. By testing it out, I have found out that for my application it should not go above 60% of its duty cycle, this being the maximum speed needed. However, it is stated in its datasheet that  -

> ["The graphite brush of motor will be abnormally wore out or the commutator interval will be blocked by carbon powder when using in condition of D/T under 60%"](https://digilent.com/reference/_media/motor_gearbox/290-006_ig220019x00015r_ds.pdf)

I really need it to operate under a duty cycle of 60%, is there any way I can make this work? Does it really get damaged by this? Should I look for another motor?

Comment: What type of motor, size etc are we talking about. I use to have the motors checked every 12 months and brushes replaced. These were in the range of 100Hp and larger.

Comment: What's the context for that warning in the datasheet? If it's for the motor to be operating at rated power, with a higher than rated input voltage, effectively reduced by PWM, that sounds plausible. However if you are trying to regulate the speed and power down below rated, with your rated input voltage, then I'm not sure what the warning means, other than this is a very fragile motor. If the current is continuous, then I would not expect any extra wear due to PWM. If discontinuous, then you could get large peak currents which might heat and damage the brushes.

Comment: @Gil the motor's datasheet is in the hyperlink of the quote. It is a brushed DC motor rated at 12V. I don't need to use it for a prolonged period of time, as it is meant for a demonstrative project of mine.

Comment: @Neil_UK I do not understand what the warning is meant for. I am only using DC Voltages in my project, not AC ones. I am using 8 AA batteries in series to power a L298 H Bridge Module which commands these motors using PWM-logic generated by a microcontroller.

Comment: If you are using PWM, then there's an AC component as well as a DC component to the drive. Personally, I'd be inclined to ignore these warnings. The motor will wear out when it wears out. High frequency PWM will result in a continuous current, where the current ramps up during on time, and down during off time. Low frequency PWM may result  in discontuinpus current, whent he current ramsp down and stops in the off time. In order to get the correct average current, you may have very large current peaks during the on time. This is the only damage mechanism I can think of.